# Мобильная точка доступа WiFi

Tags: c#, wifi

Какие существуют способы создания мобильной точки доступа via C#?

Про использование `netsh` и парсинга ответов из него же знаю. Но, способ мягко говоря не очень.

Нужно:

1. Выбор режима шифрования пароля;
2. Выбор источника данных (сетевая карта, например, или тот же WiFi-адаптер, как это сейчас сделано в Win 10);
3. Выбор, куда передавать данные (другая сетевая карта, WiFi-адаптер, etc)

[Самая удачная, на мой взгляд, реализация с использованием netsh.](https://github.com/jurruh/WifiHotspotDotNet)

Comment: А поделитесь способом с CMD с остальными участниками? (Можно ссылкой.)

Comment: @VladD привел пример.

Comment: Что-то не нравится мне такая реализация. Она просто вызывает `netsh` и сравнивает ответ с константами типа `The hosted network mode has been set to allow. `. Это отвратительно грубый хак, и очевидно не будет работать на неанглийской системе. Ну или если тексты в каком-нибудь апдейте поменяют на более вежливые, например.

Comment: @VladD так вот в том то и дело, что больше информации о том, как работать с WiFi найти не могу, да, есть библиотеки, которые позволяют  работать с WiFi, но только с приемом сигнала...

Comment: Ага, нашёл. Вот функции в WinAPI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx. Вот последовательность для старта: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815252(v=vs.85).aspx (секция «Start Sequence for Wireless Hosted Network»). Вот P/Invoke-определения для этого: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi.WlanHostedNetworkStartUsing. В принципе, с этим можно уже работать.